# Menu buttons with accordion effects

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, accordion

I'm trying to create an accordion button ([Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/0kyD9SFeVc)).

I have a side menu of buttons that trigger information on the side. I want to make the information accordion so that only 1 row of information is shown at a time.

How do I do that?

```
<div class="col-sm-2 row side">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#f1" data-parent="#accordion">Farm Fresh Produce</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#f2" data-parent="#accordion">Building 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#f3" data-parent="#accordion">Building 2</button>
</div>

<section class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div class="row collapse" id="f1">
        <p>Stuff 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row collapse " id="f2">
        <p>Stuff 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row collapse " id="f3">
        <p>Stuff 3</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/IJiNihR2ux)

```
<div class="col-sm-2 row side">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#f1" data-parent="#accordion">Farm Fresh Produce</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#f2" data-parent="#accordion">Building 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#f3" data-parent="#accordion">Building 2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#f4" data-parent="#accordion">Building 3</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#f5" data-parent="#accordion">Building 4</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#f6" data-parent="#accordion">North Street of Shops</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#f7" data-parent="#accordion">South Street of Shops</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#f8" data-parent="#accordion">Center Street of Shops</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#f9" data-parent="#accordion">Open Air Market</button>
</div>

<section class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="row panel-collapse collapse" id="f1">
                <p>Stuff 1</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="row panel-collapse collapse " id="f2">
                <p>Stuff 2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="row panel-collapse collapse " id="f3">
                <p>Stuff 3</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="row panel-collapse collapse " id="f4">
                <p>Stuff 4</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="row panel-collapse collapse " id="f5">
                <p>Stuff 5</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="row panel-collapse collapse " id="f6">
                <p>Stuff 6</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="row panel-collapse collapse " id="f7">
                <p>Stuff 7</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="row panel-collapse collapse " id="f8">
                <p>Stuff 8</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="row panel-collapse collapse " id="f9">
                <p>Stuff 9</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation of [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#f1">Farm Fresh Produce</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="f1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
            Stuff 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#f2">Building 1</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="f2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
            Stuff 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#f3">Building 2</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="f3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
            Stuff 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Not a solution. The Data-parent option only applies with panel class. My buttons are located outside the panel class.

Comment: `            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('.accordion').click(function() {
                    for (var i = 0; i > 9; i++) {
                        $('#f' + i).collapse()();
                        console.log('#f' + i);
                    }
                    $($(this).data('target')).collapse();
                });
            });` this doesn't work either